# Incompatible operand types String and char syntax error

Tags: java, eclipse, joptionpane

**Awesome guys I got this to work correcting my comparisons and my IF statement but I am now working on the console to print the information as on the file. No more error codes however console just says java.io.PrintWriter.....any pointers on how to use outputFile and import javax.swing.JOptionPane ? Corrected code below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StudentFile {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Declare and initialize variables
        String studentSummary = "Student Summary Report";
        String eligibleBachelorsReport = "Eligible Bachelors Report";

        // input record
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String gender;
        int age;
        String maritalStatus;

        // counters
        int marriedMen = 0;
        int singleMen = 0;
        int marriedWomen = 0;
        int singleWomen = 0;

        // create studentInput to read from StudentFile.txt
        File inputFile = new File("StudentFile.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            // read name, gender, age, maritalStatus
            firstName = input.next();
            lastName = input.next();
            gender = input.next();
            age = input.nextInt();
            maritalStatus = input.next();


            if (gender.equals("F"))
            {
                if(maritalStatus.equals("M"))
                {
                marriedWomen = marriedWomen ++;
                }

                else {
                   singleWomen = singleWomen ++;
                 }
            }
            else if (maritalStatus.equals("M")){
                marriedMen = marriedMen++;
            }else{
                singleMen = singleMen++;
            }

                if( age > 30) {
                    eligibleBachelorsReport += " "+firstName + " "+lastName;
     }
            System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + gender + " " + age + " "
                    + maritalStatus);
        }

        // write studentSummary, eligibleBachelorsReport to StudentReport.txt
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("StudentReport.txt");
        outputFile.println(studentSummary);
        outputFile.println(eligibleBachelorsReport);

        // write studentSummary, eligibleBachelorsReport to the console
        System.out.println(studentSummary);
        System.out.println(eligibleBachelorsReport);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputFile);

        input.close();
        outputFile.close();
     }}
```

I am trying to get this code to work and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. i understand that I am trying to compare the string data in this text file that I've imported/attached to this program but it can't seem to go through.

The code I have is below and the txt file that I have imported is labeled StudentFile.txt and has three rows of information in the following order: name, gender, age, marital status
Ex: Mick Jagger M 22 S

What am I doing wrong and why do I keep getting syntax errors? I'm using easy eclipse and I can generally find what I've done wrong with this by using their debugger but I'm kinda stuck. Please help! thx

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StudentFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Declare and initialize variables
        String studentSummary = "Student Summary Report";
        String eligibleBachelorsReport = "Eligible Bachelors Report";

        // input record
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String gender;
        int age;
        String maritalStatus;

        // counters
        int marriedMen = 0;
        int singleMen = 0;
        int marriedWomen = 0;
        int singleWomen = 0;

        // create studentInput to read from StudentFile.txt
        File inputFile = new File("StudentFile.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            // read name, gender, age, maritalStatus
            firstName = input.next();
            lastName = input.next();
            gender = input.next();
            age = input.nextInt();
            maritalStatus = input.next();


            if (gender.equals(F)){
            }if maritalStatus.equals(M)){
                marriedWomen = marriedWomen ++;
                } else {
                singleWomen = singleWomen ++;
            }else{
                }if maritalStatus.equals(M)){
                marriedMen = marriedMen ++
            }else{
                singleMen = singleMen ++
                if age > 30 {
                    eligibleBachelorsReport += ""firstName + ""lastName
    }
            System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + gender + " " + age + " "
                    + maritalStatus);
        }

        // write studentSummary, eligibleBachelorsReport to StudentReport.txt
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("StudentReport.txt");
        outputFile.println(studentSummary);
        outputFile.println(eligibleBachelorsReport);

        // write studentSummary, eligibleBachelorsReport to the console
        System.out.println(studentSummary);
        System.out.println(eligibleBachelorsReport);

        input.close();
        outputFile.close();
    }}
```

Comment: Mick Jagger is 22 and single!?

Comment: @NullUserException I was about to flag the comment and then I saw the moderator symbol.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Feel free to flag comments from mods just like you would flag any other user.

Comment: ok I think I got this, so now I've corrected the way I compare the strings using .equals()) and my IF statements in () now the program runs correctly however I cannot seem to get my console to print the correct info. It pops up so I get no errors but the console just says "java.io.PrintWriter" instead of republishing the report in the file. Any pointers on how to use the :import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

Comment: lol @ NullUserException--according my java prof he is...Martha Stewart is also 23 and married.

Answer (score 3):

Review your string comparisons for gender:

```
gender.equals(F)){
        }if maritalStatus.equals(M)){
```

You're using bare tokens here, and *not* comparing against the strings `"M"`, and `"F"`.

Also look over that code, you have a syntax error there - and in many of your `if` statements - and an empty block if `gender.equals("F")`, and you're stringing together multiple `else` statements, instead of using intermediate `else if`.

This is incorrect:

```
if (test)
{

}
else
{ ; }
else // wrong, can only have one final else
{ ; }
```

For three branches, you need an intervening `if`:

```
if (test)
{

}
else if (someOtherTest)
{

}
else // ok, one final else
{ ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (gender.equals(F))
```

`F` is no variable in your code.. You should use "F" here to compare..

Also, you are using your if as:  - `if age > 30`.. This is not the correct way..
You need to put brackets around: - `if (age > 30)`

Answer (score 0):

You say `if (gender.equals(F))`, but what is F? Is that a variable you've defined somewhere? I think it's more likely that you mean the string "F". Same for `if (maritalStatus.equals(M))` (which is missing and opening parenthesis, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code. I'll try to make a quick resume (showing a single example of each case, the rest of the related issues are similar) of what I've seen so far and I'll be updating the answer if I find more:

```
gender.equals(F)
```

What's F?, It's not a defined variable nor a valid value. If you want to compare against a string you need to use quotes, like `"F"`.

```
if age > 30
```

Most statements need `()`'s to delimit what will you check. The `if` statement is one of those, requiring it to be like `if(age > 30)`. Also, remember that you need to use brackets if your if encloses more than a single line of code.

```
eligibleBachelorsReport += ""firstName + ""lastName
```

There's no need to use quotes before a `String` variable to concatenate them. Still, ig you wanted to add a blank space between the strings, do `eligibleBachelorsReport += " " + firstName + " " + lastName + " - "`. The `-` at the end is just a suggestion. Remember that if you're going to concatenate a lot of things together. Also, you can use `\n` if you need to insert a line break.

```
eligibleBachelorsReport += ""firstName + ""lastName
marriedMen = marriedMen ++
```

There's no semicolon at the end of those lines, amongst others.

```
singleMen = singleMen ++
```

Not an issue itself but unnecesary. Just do `singleMen++` which is the same than `singleMen = singleMen + 1` or also `singleMen += 1`.

As a final note, check your `if` statements. There is only one `else` per `if`, think of it as avoiding orphan `else` since there's no condition associated to them. The structure is:

```
if(condition) {

} else {

}
```

or, if the `if` and/or `else` enclose only one line (tough I always use brackets. It allows a clearer delimitation of the statements and improves readability IMHO.):

```
if(condition)
    //code
else
    //code
```

or, to nest statements:

```
if(condition) {

} else if(condition2) {

} else if(condition3) {

}
```